# proof that $\frac d {dy}\left(G(x,y)G(y,z)\right)=0 \implies G(x,y)=c_2\frac{H(x)}{H(y)}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory

Jaynes in probability theory the logic of science says that

$$\frac d {dy}\left(G(x,y)G(y,z)\right)=0 \implies G(x,y)=c_2\frac{H(x)}{H(y)}$$

Why is this true? I can see the implication going the other way of  course.

Comment: I re-asked this, and [kimchi lover](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3013064/gx-ygy-z-independant-of-y-implies-most-general-function-form-gx-y) gave a brilliant answer.